# React hook form - Register field not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-unregister-v6-forked-19446?file=/src/index.js), I'm manually registering two fields, if I click submit w/o entering any data I see required field validation, which works fine and if I unregister "lastname" it removes error from last name, however,

The problem: first name still shows required validation even if I enter data.
I tried removing manual registering a field and it work fine. But that is not my requirement.
Any help. Thank you.

Comment: answer to above answer. Basically it needs to use ref, but some case is not necessary, for example, when case of dom element isn't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setValue doesn't trigger validation by default:

https://react-hook-form.com/api#setValue

```
- onChange={(e) => setValue("firstName", e.target.value)}
+ onChange={(e) => setValue("firstName", e.target.value, { shouldValidate: true } )}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on documentation you need to use "ref" in order to register needed field.
Read here:

https://react-hook-form.com/api#register

I also updated your example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-unregister-v6-forked-6wq09?file=/src/index.js

Have fun!

Comment: that is not my use case. based on some condition, i have to register some field. not always.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. And I found that it happened because the version I installed is v6 but the official doc is v7 and the usage of `register` is different between two versions.